# AWS Lambda .NET Core Deployment Task Fails

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Using the task "AWS Lambda .NET Core Deployment" by Amazon Web Services

Successfully creates the zip file for deployment but fails on upload. My first thought was a lack of write permission, but the previous step is deploying the html, css, js to the same bucket successfully with the same AWS Credentials.

Anyone deployed a .net core 2.0 or 2.1 serverless template app to AWS Lambda in Azure DevOps and worked through a similar problem?

Here is the error with system.debug=true:

```
Uploading to S3. (Bucket: [bucketname] Key: {filename}.zip)
Error uploading to [filename].zip in bucket {bucketname}: The write operation failed, see inner exception.
[debug]rc:4294967295
[debug]success:false
[debug]task result: Failed
[error]Error: C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe failed with return code: 4294967295
[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]Error: C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe failed with return code: 4294967295
[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]Error: C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe failed with return code: 4294967295
[section]Finishing: Deploy .NET Core to Lambda:  {appname}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Somehow my AWS creds stopped working.
I changed my access key and secret key and S3 started working.
I created a new connection in AzureDevOps and it helped.